# Problema con Pasarela de pago CopyAndPay

Tags: php

Hola amigos estoy realizando una pasarela de pago con el Api Oppwa.
Le envio los parametros pero sale que faltan parametros alguna ayuda ?
 Segun la documentacion que lei esta debe generarme un token pero no me muestra ese valor que se devuelve en JSON

```
     function prepareCheckout($total,$iva,$totalTarifa12,$totalBase0,$email,$primer_nombre
    ,$segundo_nombre,$apellido,$cedula,$trx,$ip_address,$finger,$merchterm,
    $telefono,$direccion_cliente,$pais_cliente,$direccion_entrega,$pais_entrega){
         $finger = urlencode($finger);
$i =0;
$url = "https://test.oppwa.com/v1/checkouts";
$iva = str_replace('.', '', $iva);
$totalTarifa12 = str_replace('.', '', $totalTarifa12);
$totalBase0 = str_replace('.', '', $totalBase0);
$valueIva = str_pad($iva,12,'0'.STR_PAD_LEFT);
$valueTotalIva = str_pad($totalTarifa12,12,'0'.STR_PAD_LEFT);
$valueIvaTotalBase0 = str_pad($totalBase0,12,'0'.STR_PAD_LEFT);
$data = "authentication.userId=".$_SESSION['entityId']. 
   "&amount=".$total.
   "&currency=USD".
    "&paymentType=DB".
    "&customer.givenName=".$primer_nombre.
    "&customer.middleName=".$segundo_nombre.
    "&customer.surname=".$apellido.
    "&customer.ip=".$ip_address.
    "&customer.merchantCustomerId=00000000001".
    "&merchantTransactionId=transaction_".$trx.
    "&customer.email=".$email.
    "&customer.identificationDocType=IDCARD".
    "&customer.identificationDocId=".$cedula.
    "&customer.phone=".$telefono.
    "&billing.street1=".$direccion_cliente.
    "&billing.country=".$pais_cliente.
    "&shipping.street1=".$direccion_entrega.
    "&shipping.country=".$pais_entrega.
    "&risk.paramters[USER_DATA2]=MiComercio".
    "customParamters[".$merchterm."]=00810030070103910004012".$valueIva.
    "05100817913101052012".$valueIvaTotalBase0."053012".$valueTotalIva;


    $data.= "&testMode=EXTERNAL";      
      $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
         'Authorization:Bearer OGE4Mjk0MTg1MzNjZjMxZDAxNTMzZDA2ZmQwNDA3NDh8WHQ3RjIyUUVOWA=='));
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);// this should be set to true inproduction
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
         $responseData = curl_exec($ch);

        if(curl_errno($ch)) {
          return curl_error($ch);
            }
        curl_close($ch);
         return $responseData;
          }
```

Segun la documentacion que lei esta debe generarme un token pero no me muestra ese valor que se devuelve en JSON

//Aqui añado la informacion y llamo a la funcion

```
$total = 120.00;
$iva = 004012000000000012;
 $totalTarifa12 = 053012000000000100;
 $totalBase0 = 052012000000000200;
 $email = "JonathanVeraMarin98@outlook.com";
$primer_nombre = "Jonathan";
$segundo_nombre = "Fernando";
$apellido = "Vera";
$cedula = "0952152525";
$trx = 123456789;
$ip_address = '05100817913101';
$finger = 'https://test.oppwa.com/v1/checkouts';
$merchterm= '1000000505_PD100406';
$telefono ='2172161';
$direccion_cliente = 11222;
$pais_cliente = 121212;
$direccion_entrega = '1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW';
$pais_entrega = 121212;
$checkoutId=prepareCheckout
($total,$iva,$totalTarifa12,$totalBase0,
$email,$primer_nombre,$segundo_nombre,$apellido,$cedula,
   $trx,$ip_address,$finger, $merchterm,$telefono,$direccion_cliente,
$pais_cliente,$direccion_entrega,$pais_entrega);
```

// Lo que no se si hablara de los parametros de la tarjeta pero no deberian ser esos xq primero dejeme traerme el CheckoutId

Comment: ¿Dónde obtienes el error de que faltan parámetros? Seguramente es cuando llamas la función `prepareCheckout()`. Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código que usas para ejecutarla.

Comment: Listo amigo Ahi esta la llamada con los valores